# .eq() argument not working in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function createLogos() {
    for (var l=0; l<userList().length; l++) {
        var username = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" + userList()[l];
        $.getJSON(username, function(data) {
            $(":eq(l)").append("<img src=" + data.logo +">");
        });
     }
 }
```

However, the `eq(l)` is not recognising what l is.  Replacing it with a number and it works as to how I wish.

Can anyone see why it might be behaving like this?

Comment: because `l` is a string, not a reference to the variable and using it in a for loop like that after you fix the issue will be another bug. And I doubt you just want ":eq" as your selector

Comment: After the change noted above, reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?rq=1 will probably be relevant.

Comment: Before using :eq, I had this line:   $("#theTable .pic").eq(l).append("<img src=" + data.logo +">"); this did not work either, where l is not a string.

Comment: that is because of the "infamous for loop" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute `$.map()` for `for` loop, use `$.when()`

```
function createLogos() {
    $.when.apply($, $.map(userList(), function(el, index) {
      var username = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" + el;
      return $.getJSON(username, function(data) {
        $("#theTable .pic").eq(index).append("<img src=" + data.logo +">");
      })
    }))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are looking for index `l` not the current index of the loop. Now id you were do do it by referencing the variable you will have a different problem since l will be evaluated when the code is hit so it will be the wrong value.

So what you need to be is reference the element before the JSON call

```
function createLogos() {
    for (var l=0; l<userList().length; l++){
        var username = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" + userList()[l],
            pic = $("#theTable .pic").eq(l);
        $.getJSON(username, function(data){
            pic.append("<img src=" + data.logo +">");
        });
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate `:eq()`
Hope it will work

```
function createLogos() {
 for (var l=0; l<userList().length; l++){
    var username = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" + userList()[l];
    $.getJSON(username, function(data){
       $(":eq("+l+")").append("<img src=" + data.logo +">");
    })
 }
}
```